# System.Drawing.Image and colour spaces

Tags: .net, image-processing

If I create a bitmap with `System.Drawing.Bitmap` How can I specify what colour space the bitmap uses? Also how can I make sure the colour profile is embedded when I save the image as a jpeg or tiff?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I have found the answer to this.

The colour space is recorded in the image's `PropertyItems`

It has an ID of 40961 which is it's EXIF ID.

So I would presume that adding an instance of this property to a newly created bitmap would give the image a colour space.

There is a big problem though. `System.Drawing.Imaging.PropertyItem` class does not have a public constructor. So it is not possible to create a  new `PropertyItem`. It says in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.imaging.propertyitem.aspx) that PropertyItems are only meant for accessing existing image metadata and not creating metadata. So what if I want to create an entirely new image and assign it a colour space with a  `PropertyItem`?

It also says in the documentation that if I wish to create a new `PropertyItem` that I should get an existing `PropertyItem`, clone it, edit the clone, and add the clone to `PropertyItems`. However if I am creating a new image there will not be any existing `PropertyItems`. So how am I supposed to add a `PropertyItem` that declares a colour space?

Comment: Two options -- if you want to assign certain predefined colourspace values, you could just include one or more "template" 1x1 pixel JPEG files just to load them in and find their PropertyItem objects. If you need to dynamically set colourspaces you don't know at development time, you might need to peer into the internal structure of the JPEG file, and then include a template where you know you can overwrite a particular byte offset to set an arbitrary colourspace value. With that, you could generate whatever PropertyItem values you needed on-demand.